# Change the Order of the Footnotes

Tags: ms-word

I would like to [change the footnote in the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLgWL.jpg). More specifically I want to put the full stop after the footnote [like in this concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0RlR.png).
Online seems the only solution is with a macro, but I have no idea where to start.

I've only found this script close to the solution

```
Sub UpdateFootnotes()
'Update fields in all footnotes.
Dim doc As Document
Dim rng As Range
Set doc = ActiveDocument
If doc.Footnotes.Count <> 0 Then
'Select all footnotes.    
Set rng = doc.Footnotes(1).Range
rng.WholeStory
rng.Select
'Update all fields. 
Selection.Fields.Update
End If
End Sub
```

I need to do it for my bachelor thesis, it would really help me a lot!

Edit: from a posted answer in [Microsoft forums here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2016/change-the-order-of-the-footnotes/a768f357-8564-428b-8b48-1f92c6067f47?tm=1610361186725)

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-the-order-of-the-footnotes/a768f357-8564-428b-8b48-1f92c6067f47. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro you found has nothing to do with changing the position of footnote references; it simply updates any fields in footnotes.

The following macro processes footnotes and endnotes.

```
Sub FootnoteEndnoteFix()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FtNt As Footnote, EndNt As Endnote, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For Each FtNt In .Footnotes
    Set Rng = FtNt.Reference
    With Rng
      'Eliminate any spaces before the footnote
      While .Characters.First.Previous.Text = " "
        .Characters.First.Previous.Text = vbNullString
      Wend
      'Swap the footnote/punctuation, as applicable
      Select Case .Characters.First.Previous
        Case ".", ",", "!", "?", ":", ";"
          .InsertAfter .Characters.First.Previous
          .Characters.First.Previous.Text = vbNullString
          .Characters.Last.Font.Superscript = False
      End Select
    End With
  Next
  For Each EndNt In .Endnotes
    Set Rng = EndNt.Reference
    With Rng
      'Eliminate any spaces before the endnote
      While .Characters.First.Previous.Text = " "
        .Characters.First.Previous.Text = vbNullString
      Wend
      'Swap the endnote/punctuation, as applicable
      Select Case .Characters.First.Previous
        Case ".", ",", "!", "?", ":", ";"
          .InsertAfter .Characters.First.Previous
          .Characters.First.Previous.Text = vbNullString
          .Characters.Last.Font.Superscript = False
      End Select
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And the tip of the cross-answer I didn't knew nothing. I thought my post would be ignored but I had to mention of both posts as I did now.